# React sidebar took full width

Tags: css, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, sidebar

so I'm trying to create a dashboard page which will show sidebar after user login, But I don't know why my sidebar is taking full width that make my Dashboard component on Routes drop into bottom.

This is the image link of the sidebar https://i.stack.imgur.com/sumW0.jpg

My code on App.js :

```
import Login from './Component/Login';
import Register from './Component/Register.jsx'
import Home from './Component/Home'
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Routes,
  Route,
} from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" element={<Login/>}/>
          <Route path="/register" element={<Register/>}/>
          <Route  path="/dashboard" element={<Home/>}/>
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

my code for Home.js:

```
import React from "react";
import Sidebar from './Sidebar'
import Dashboard from "./Dashboard";
import {Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom'
import './Home.css'

function Home() {
  return (
    <>
   <Sidebar/>   
      <Routes>
          <Route  index  element={<Dashboard/>}/>
        </Routes>
      </>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

The Dashboard Component is just 80 of Lorem text.

This is the code in Sidebar.js and Sidebar.css

```
import React from 'react'
import './Sidebar.css'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'

function Sidebar() {
  return (
    <div>
      <nav className="sidebar">
        <Link to="/dashboard">DashBoard</Link>
      </nav>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Sidebar
```

the Sidebar.css :

```
.sidebar{
    display:flex;
    width:200px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    height:100vh;
    background-color:#FFD302;
}
```

I don't know if  this the problem with the CSS or the Router dom. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Home` component controls the layout of the HTML/JSX it is rendering. I suggest using a grid layout with 2 columns, one for the sidebar and the other for the descendent routes.

Example:

```
.home {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}
```

...

```
function Home() {
  return (
    <div className="home"> // <-- parent element
      <Sidebar />
      <Routes>
        <Route index element={<Dashboard />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit react-sidebar-took-full-width]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try to write your css in sperate file and then attach it by importing i think that is a right way to do work.

Comment: sorry, the css was in seperate file. I just post it wrong. let me fix it.